# Word to include grammatical errors upon printing (green and red underlines)

Tags: microsoft-word

For my sister's Exam sheets, she wants to print word documents including the grammatical errors (green, red and blue zigzag underlines) so that her students can correct it. 
I suggested simply placing line shapes on the grammatically incorrect words, but is there a way to include said error lines?

I typed in google ("include grammatically error lines when printing word") but it did not yield good results.

Comment: What she ended up doing is to simply print screen and edit the image to make it appear like a document. Crude, but it got the job done. 
Still curious if this is possible still.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro to add actual coloured wavy underlining to the errors in the text for you, then print that out.

```
Sub addlines()
Dim err As Object
    For Each err In ActiveDocument.Range.GrammaticalErrors
        With err.Font
            .Underline = wdUnderlineWavy
            .UnderlineColor = wdColorGreen
        End With
    Next
    For Each err In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
        With err.Font
            .Underline = wdUnderlineWavy
            .UnderlineColor = wdColorRed
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```